# ¿Como hago para abrir otro dialogo desde un setPositiveButton?

Tags: android, android-studio, alertdialog, diálogo

Quiero que este dialogo cuando elijan los ítems, y le den a compartir lo mande a otro dialogo de confirmación, para que este muestre un toast con los elementos seleccionados.

Esta parte funciona bien:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

final String[] lenguajes = {"Facebook","Twitter","instagram","Google Plus","Whatsapp","Messenger","SMS"};
final boolean[] checked = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false};

builder.setTitle("Selecciona dónde quieres compartir esta aplicación");
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(lenguajes, checked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("COMPARTIR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        String result = "";
        int cont = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<checked.length;i++){
            if (checked[i])
                if ((cont != ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemCount())) {
                    result += lenguajes[i]+", ";
                    cont++;
                }
                else result += lenguajes[i];
        }
        if (result == ""){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Para Compartir tiene que selecionar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

## Hasta que llega a esta parte#

el programa se cierra y no sé porque, o es porque tal vez tengo dos dialogo en uno.

```
        else {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

            builder1.setTitle("Confirmación");
            builder1.setMessage("¿Compartir esta aplicación a través de los medios seleccionados?");

            builder1.setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            });

            builder1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Datos NO guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }

    }

});
return builder.create();
```

## ayuda estoy trabajando en un proyecto

Comment: Te aconsejo que revises el LogCat, en el mismo debería de venir los errores o al menos alguna pista de donde se encuentra el error. Si en el LogCat no te aparece nada trata de correr el app en un emulador o en un dispositivo físico incluso reinicia el dispositivo si aún no ves en el LogCat. En versiones recientes de Android Studio en el LogCat aparece un apartado para cuando la aplicación se detiene Suerte!

Comment: El LogCat, me muestra este error:

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                               Process: com.example.usuario.redessociales, PID: 3956
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:103)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:256)  at

Comment: com.example.usuario.redessociales.DialogoConfirmacion$3$1.onClick(DialogoConfirmacion.java:66) at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: No utilices ni los comentarios, ni trates de editar respuestas de otros para añadir información importante para tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] en tu propia pregunta para editarla y ahí es donde debes añadir en este caso el error del logcat

Comment: @RomeroAracena la información  debes agregarla a tu pregunta mediante el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/118896/edit). No es clara tu pregunta, el código no muestra información sobre si estas dentro de Activity, Fragment, Service, etc.

Answer (score 1):

El error mas común es el contexto:

Si los `dialog` están en el `activity` principal, el primer `dialog` se coloca como contexto: "this" y el segundo que es el que esta dentro del primero, se coloca el mismo contexto de la actividad pero como ya se esta utilizando(duplicando) "this" solo se coloca el nombre del `activity` seguido de:

```
"this": "nombreActivity.this"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto :

```
 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

En lugar de getContext() usa:

Si estás en una Actividad

```
 Toast.makeText(TuActividad.this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Si estás en un Fragmento

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: ¿Porque no usar getContext()?, lo que debemos es proponerle a la persona que pregunta, agregué datos específicos. De hecho getContext() lo usa en varias partes de su programa.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero ni siquiera escribe como le fue con esta respuesta :/ , no tengo mucha info

Comment: Hola Diego, de hecho le pregunte si es  Activity, Fragment, Service, etc, :( no lo sabemos. De hecho en una Activity en ocasiones uso el contexto de la aplicación también.

Comment: Disculpa diegoveloper, cambiar los el geContext, por getActivity, y sigue igual.
Si le quito el Toast, el programa funcióna pero necesito que presente el Toast para guardar los datos.

Comment: ok, puedes indicarnos el error que te aparece, actualiza tu pregunta con el LOG de error